# Firefox cache not working, Last-Modified header ignored

Tags: http, firefox, web, http-headers, browser-cache

I'm developing a web app and I'm trying to cache the result of a query in the browser.

I send the Last-Modified header, and it works as expected on Chrome. The server gets the If-Modified-Since header and I can return the status 304 (not modified).

However Firefox does not send If-Modified-Since.

**EDIT**

After some investigation, this seems to be related to the "Connection: close" header sent by a router.
Why does it break the cache on Firefox? If you have an explanation, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand the problem, but I found a solution. If I send the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, the cache works again.